# Is there a jQuery-like library for Flex?

Tags: jquery, apache-flex

Does anyone know of a library that would allow me to manipulate Flex "DOM" and assign events in such an elegant way that jQuery uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [AS3Query](http://ajaxian.com/archives/as3query-jquery-port-to-actionscript), a direct port of JQuery to Actionscript.

It would be cool if there was, it would just come at a decent performance cost.

Comment: I know of AS3Query but that project never really took off. Still, it's probably the best answer, thanks.